# Socket Programming using java

Tags: java, sockets, wireshark

I am sent simple chat messages from client to server using threads and tcp protocol. But when i look into the details of the packet using wireshark i saw that my data getting divided for eg.. my MSS=1460, if i am sending a data of 780 bytes..1st few bytes goes into 1st segment and the rest in 2nd..number of bytes going in the packets is random. what should i do inorder to utilize my network's full capacity??. At first i thought i was getting this since i was using DataInputStream/OpStream but when i changed it to bufferedreader the problem remains the same.
PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: @jkbkot UDP has absolutely nothing to do with this question. It is specifically about TCP.

Comment: Are you sure? Fragmentation is handled below TCP. TCP provides a stream of continuous data, you don't have to deal with packets, which is answered in the question I linked (and many others on SO). With UDP you'll also receive the full packet, not fragments. You just may not receive it at all.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `BufferedOutputStream` or `BufferedWriter` to send, and only flush when you really need to, e.g. before reading.

Comment: i used printwriter to print the message on the server.

Comment: What you used to 'print the message on the server' is completely and utterly irrelevant. I am telling you want to use when *sending.* Please read what I actually wrote before you comment.